# Use the list of arguments to a method in C++

Tags: c++, templates

This is what I would like to do -- I have a class A with several constructors. I do not want to change anything in class A. I would like to have a new class B, and A should be an element of B and have a constructors which mirror A.

```
class A{
public:
   A(type1 arg1);
   A(type2 arg1, type3 arg2); 
}
```

I know I can do this

```
class B{
A *a;
public:
   B(type1 arg1) {
      a = new A(arg1);
      //some other stuff here
   }
   B(type2 arg1, type3 arg2) {
      a = new A(arg1, arg2);
      //some other stuff here, same as the first constructor
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

```
class B{
A *a;
public:
   B(list_of_args) {
      a = new A(list_of_args);
      //some other stuff here
   }
}
```

I do not want to extend A. I am just looking for a way to get the list of arguments passed to B and call the constructor of A with this. (without making changes to A).

Comment: Thanks @Deduplicator, will fix it. This gets me everytime!

Comment: While the question can be answered technically, the more interesting question is about the design. I find it unusual to have to *generically* forward arguments to a type that is well known, other than saving typing which is not a good reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With C++11 and variadic templates, easy:

```
class B {
    A a;

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    B(Args&&... args)
    : a(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    { }
};
```

Without variadic templates, you could just add a bunch of template constructors for various amounts of arguments, but it's pretty ugly. If none of the args are references, it's not *so* bad

```
template <typename A1> 
B(const A1& a1) : a(a1) { }

template <typename A1, typename A2> 
B(const A1& a1, const A2& a2) : a(a1, a2) { }
// etc.
```

But really, you'd want to handle `A1&` and `const A1&` separately... so you'd need `2^N` constructors for `N` arguments. You can see why people were excited about C++11.

(note that in your code, you had a class member of type `A` but in your constructor example you are trying to create an `A*`).

Comment: While this will work, it might also create code bloat if the compiler does not inline the constructor. Consider that the only constructor for `A` is `A(int)` and that different parts of the program called it with `B(1)`, `B(1u)`, `B(1.)`, `B(1.f)`, `B(1s)`... The whole question is a bit of a code smell, really. There are very few occasions where this [what the OP wants] would not be a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You make a templated constructor and employ variadic template arguments:

```
class B
{
public:
   template<typename... ArgTypes>
   B(ArgTypes... list_of_args) : a(list_of_args...)
   {
     //some other stuff here
   }
private:
  A a;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a963dad87cd1503).

---

As in @Barry's answer and as mentioned in the comments, it is better to use `ArgTypes&&` and `std::forward` to allow for move-only types and some efficiency. [Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c02d858a0d87a5d):

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
B(ArgTypes&&... list_of_args) : a(std::forward<ArgTypes>(list_of_args)...)
{
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to forward the argument list? Efficiency aside, this fails, for example, if one of the parameters is a move-only type.

Comment: @Ben no reason except not thinking of that case. Edited in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adapting Barry's solution to your demand:

```
class A{
public:
   A(type1 arg1);
   A(type2 arg1, type3 arg2); 
}



class B{
A *a;
public:
   template <typename... Args>
   B(Args&&... args) {
      a = new A(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      //some other stuff here
   }
}
```

The other way is to declare a member method to call in place of "//some other stuff here" for each B constructor.

```
class B{
A *a;
public:
   void initialize(A* a) {
      this->a = a;
      //some other stuff here
   }

   B(type1 arg1) {
      initialize(new A(arg1));
   }

   B(type2 arg1, type3 arg2) {
      initialize(new A(arg1, arg2));
   }
}
```